# how to convert a 1d z-axis to 2d array for a contour plot?

Tags: arrays, matplotlib, contour

I have 1600 x-coordinates and 1600 y-coordinates by using the np.meshgrid, I'll able to create a 2d array of size (1600x1600). I also have a 1600 values of 1d array which will be used as the z-coordinates. The ax.contourf demands for a z-axis to be a 2d array. So, how to convert these z-coordinates from 1d to 2d array?

```
x_list = 1600 values
y_list = 1600 values
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_list, y_list)
Z = np.linspace(min(Z), max(Z), 1600*1600).reshape(X.shape)
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
colors=["red", "orange", "gold", "limegreen"]
contour = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z, colors=colors)
cmap = mpc.ListedColormap(colors)
contour = ax2.contourf(X,Y,Z, cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(contour)
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code, the line

```
Z = np.linspace(min(Z), max(Z), 1600*1600).reshape(X.shape)
```

is wrong.

You have to define a 1D array`z_list` first.

The following should work:

```
import random
import matplotlib.colors as mpc
x_list = range(0,1600)
y_list = range(0,1600)
z_list = []

for i in range(0,1600):
  z_list.append(random.randint(1,30)) #the specific depends on your problem.

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_list, y_list)
Z = np.linspace(min(z_list), max(z_list), 1600*1600).reshape(X.shape)
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
colors=["red", "orange", "gold", "limegreen"]
contour = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet')
cmap = mpc.ListedColormap(colors)
contour = ax2.contourf(X,Y,Z, cmap=cmap)
```

[image: enter code here]